# Issue with SNS unsubscribe using CLI

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sns

I have written a code which generates below AWS CLI command to unsubscribe my lambda from certain SNS. Somehow after executing that command do not give any exception but it is not even un-subscribing the SNS as well. Any suggestions here?

`aws sns --region 'us-east-1' unsubscribe --subscription-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXX:topicName-f0c5-4e6a-867f-308c2286ef97" --generate-cli-skeleton --profile 'AWSProfile'`

This might sound silly but I am not able to figure it out. Thanks in advance guys..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--generate-cli-skeleton` option is documented as:

> Prints a JSON skeleton to standard output without sending an API request.

Therefore, this is preventing the API request from being sent.

**Solution:** Remove `--generate-cli-skeleton` from your request